# Is it possible to calculate a GRU RNN in its entirety by hand on a small dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, data-science

I want to see whether my code works and want to do it by hand to compare the results. How exactly does the memory cell work in the first example seen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.